# Convert Javascript tree object to another tree object

Tags: javascript

I have a tree object that looks like this:

```
let treeArray = [{
  id: 'x/y/z',
  status: 'Not Ready',
  application: 'x',
  artifactID: 'z',
  parent: 'None',
  children: [{
    id: 'a/b/c',
    status: 'Not Ready',
    application: 'a',
    artifactID: 'c',
    parent: 'x/y/z',
    children: [{
      id: 'p/q/r',
      status: 'Not Ready',
      application: 'p',
      artifactID: 'r',
      parent: 'a/b/c',
      children: []
    }]
  }]
}]
```

I need to convert this to the following:

```
let result = 
  [ { id: 1, target: 'x', status: 'Not Ready'} 
  , { id: 2, target: 'z', status: 'Not Ready', parentID: 1 } 
  , { id: 3, target: 'a', status: 'Not Ready', parentID: 2 } 
  , { id: 4, target: 'c', status: 'Not Ready', parentID: 3 }
  , { id: 5, target: 'p', status: 'Not Ready', parentID: 4 } 
  , { id: 6, target: 'r', status: 'Not Ready', parentID: 5 } 
  ]
```

What is the best possible way to achieve this please?

EDIT: The desired format has changed. Just note that there could be any number of elements in the children. Here i have only one element in children.

Comment: Please share your attempt as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: how do you get target value @santhosh?

Comment: @ggorlen misterJojo style was kinda fun; and wouldn't harm readabilty;

Comment: Show some effort OP. However, you can _do while_ the current object that has the children array that is not empty; also for target split the string by "/" and use the first item.

Comment: The style is beside the point. I'd have left if had you not added the defacing comment. This isn't "my" style, this is Stack Snippets' autoformatter style, which is there for a reason.

Comment: I saw what happened, but please use the comments section, not the post body, to discuss the disagreement. Yes, the original was in poor shape and your first edit was a reasonable improvement, but subsequent edits after EugenSunic were not in line with OP's intent. See [etiquette for modifying posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/6243352).

Comment: @Leonardo Thank you for your comment

Comment: @ggorlen Ok, I'll do it like this next time (hoping there won't be any)

Comment: Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @santosh can we expect the `treeArray` to grow further than the third child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the perfect application for a recursive function, that way it can run on however many children it needs to.

Basically, for each element of the tree, you build the flattened version, and then if it has children, call the same function on the children so they get parsed and added to the array in the exact same way.

I used nested functions so that calling the function on an array returns a new array, without modifying the original array, and without global variables.

The one thing I modified from the result in the question is I included the `parent` attribute on all elements, but made it return null if there is no parent, making its function and value very explicit, which helps if you plan on further processing the array returned from any function. Any number would be wrong, because there is no parent at that ID number, and omitting it makes the structure variable.

```
const expandTree = tree => {
  let id = 0;
  const flattened = [];

  const expandBranch = (tree, parentId) => {
      tree.forEach(branch => {
        id ++;
        flattened.push({
            id: id,
            target: branch.id[0],
            status: branch.status,
            parentID: parentId,
          })
        if (branch.children.length > 0) {
          expandBranch(branch.children, id)
        }
      }
    )
  };
  expandBranch(tree, null);
  return flattened;
};
```

The advantage is it still works for any number of children, on any branch of the tree:

```js
const treeArray = [{
  id: 'x/y/z',
  status: 'Not Ready',
  application: 'x',
  artifactID: 'z',
  parent: 'None',
  children: [{
    id: 'a/b/c',
    status: 'Not Ready',
    application: 'a',
    artifactID: 'c',
    parent: 'x/y/z',
    children: [{
      id: 'p/q/r',
      status: 'Not Ready',
      application: 'p',
      artifactID: 'r',
      parent: 'a/b/c',
      children: []
    }]
  }]
},
{
  id: 'x/y/z',
  status: 'Not Ready',
  application: 'x',
  artifactID: 'z',
  parent: 'None',
  children: [{
    id: 'a/b/c',
    status: 'Not Ready',
    application: 'a',
    artifactID: 'c',
    parent: 'x/y/z',
    children: [{
      id: 'p/q/r',
      status: 'Not Ready',
      application: 'p',
      artifactID: 'r',
      parent: 'a/b/c',
      children: [{
        id: 'p/q/r',
        status: 'Not Ready',
        application: 'p',
        artifactID: 'r',
        parent: 'a/b/c',
        children: []
      },{
        id: 'p/q/r',
        status: 'Not Ready',
        application: 'p',
        artifactID: 'r',
        parent: 'a/b/c',
        children: []
      },{
        id: 'p/q/r',
        status: 'Not Ready',
        application: 'p',
        artifactID: 'r',
        parent: 'a/b/c',
        children: []
      }
      ]
    }]
  }]
}]

const expandTree = tree => {
  let id = 0;
  const flattened = [];

  const expandBranch = (tree, parentId) => {
      tree.forEach(branch => {
        id ++;
        flattened.push({
            id: id,
            target: branch.id[0],
            status: branch.status,
            parentID: parentId,
          })
        if (branch.children.length > 0) {
          expandBranch(branch.children, id)
        }
      }
    )
  };
  expandBranch(tree, null);
  return flattened;
};

console.log(expandTree(treeArray))
```

Comment: @MosiaThabo oops... I hate that kind of typo, fixed now

Comment: Ryan, your solution is great. The desired format of data has changed. I've edited my post. i tried tweaking your solution but it wouldnt work.

Comment: @santosh how did it change? You didn’t add an explanation and your example appears to have multiple flattened rows created per branch of the tree, which is easy to do if you just duplicate the `flattened.push({})` block, but it makes the parentId relationship ambiguous in the case of multiple children—which row should be the parent?

Comment: Hi Ryan, It's just a requirement of how we want to display the tree. Correct, it has two rows flattened per branch. I tried duplicating flattened.push() but i think i am messing up in handling parentId and tree depth.

Comment: ParentId and tree depth are ambiguous now, that’s the problem, because each child has two parents; your attributes suggest a one-to-many relationship but with multiple parents you have a many-to-many relationship so a single parentId doesn’t really make sense. To get the output in your question I think you’d need to duplicate both `id++` and `flatten.push()` but without an example with multiple children it doesn’t really make sense.

Comment: Finally managed to get it working. But thanks for your your help. It was super useful.

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple recursive problem

```js
const treeArray = 
  [ { id: 'x/y/z', status: 'Not Ready', application: 'x', artifactID: 'z', parent: 'None', children: 
      [ { id: 'a/b/c', status: 'Not Ready', application: 'a', artifactID: 'c', parent: 'x/y/z', children: 
          [ { id: 'p/q/r', status: 'Not Ready', application: 'p', artifactID: 'r', parent: 'a/b/c', children: [] } 
  ] } ] } ] 
  ;
let result = []
  , count  = 0
  ;
function addResultRows( elm, key )
  {
  elm.forEach(elm=>
    {
    newItem = { id: ++count, target: elm.application, status: elm.status }
    if (key > 0 ) newItem.parentId = key
    result.push(newItem)
    if ( elm.children.length > 0)
      {
      addResultRows( elm.children, newItem.id ) 
      }
    })
  }
addResultRows( treeArray, 0 )
  ;
console.log( JSON.stringify( result ,0, 2)  )
  ;
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const treeArray = [{
  id: 'x/y/z',
  status: 'Not Ready',
  application: 'x',
  artifactID: 'z',
  parent: 'None',
  children: [{
    id: 'a/b/c',
    status: 'Not Ready',
    application: 'a',
    artifactID: 'c',
    parent: 'x/y/z',
    children: [{
      id: 'p/q/r',
      status: 'Not Ready',
      application: 'p',
      artifactID: 'r',
      parent: 'a/b/c',
      children: []
    }]
  }]
}]

const newArr = []

function splitArr(arr, id) {
  const obj = arr[0]
  newArr.push({
    id,
    target: obj.application,
    status: obj.status,
    parentID: id - 1
  })

  if (obj.children.length) {
    splitArr(obj.children, ++id)
  }
}

splitArr(treeArray, 1)
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if there are multiple children, I think the `parentID` would point to the previous sibling instead of the parent?

Comment: you have added a `parentID: 0` which should not exist

Comment: I hate to pile on, but the other issue with this and many of the solutions in this thread has been non-idempotency. Running the code more than once produces different results--on the second call to `splitArr`, `newArr` will still have stale results from the first run. Variables should be scoped to the function. Variable names can be improved as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
let counter = 1;
function flatit(arr, parent) {
    let arrResult = [];

    arr.forEach(el => {
        let newEl = {
            id: counter,
            target: el.application,
            status: el.status
        };

        if (parent) newEl.parent = parent;
        arrResult.push(newEl);        
        if (el.children) flatit(el.children, counter++).forEach(elc => arrResult.push(elc));
    });

    return arrResult;
}

console.log(flatit(treeArray));
```

Result:

```
[
  { id: 1, status: 'Not Ready', target: 'x' },
  { id: 2, status: 'Not Ready', target: 'a', parentID: 1 },
  { id: 3, status: 'Not Ready', target: 'p', parentID: 2 }
]
```